# Conditional rendering with typescript -

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web, frontend

When trying to conditionally render something from a datastructure, I want the element to appear if there exists a record of it in the dataset, but not if it doesnt. My attempt for this was this:

```
// other code...

{patient.address[0]
    ? patient.address[0].line[0]
    : null}

// other code...
```

This works for instances where the field is present, but when it isnt - i get a " TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

I think the problem is that when trying to access .address[0], the error gets thrown due to the array not existing on the dataset, before it can enter the conditional. How can I ammend my approach to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a couple of question marks:

```
patient?.address?.[0]?.line?.[0];
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware this was possible, and simplified the task.

Answer (score 1):

You can check in different ways

- Using optional chaining like below, you can explore more about Optional chaining [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
{patient?.address?.[0]?.line?.[0] ?? null}
```

- By using default values like below

```
{((patient || {}).address || [])[0]
    ? ((((patient || {}).address || [])[0]).line || [])[0]
    : null}
```

Simplified version of above

```
let address = ((patient || {}).address || [])[0]
{ address ? (address.line || [])[0] : null}
```

Comment: You don't need ternary with your first example, since it already defaults to `undefined`. If you really need `null` instead (which you don't, it's the same thing in React render), you can simplify it to `patient?.address?.[0]?.line?.[0] ?? null`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nithish, and thank you for the comment, @ritaj. I was wondering about exactly that, as this is how it reacted in my app.

Comment: `?? null` would be still needed, if you return the value directly in `render`/ the function body.

Comment: No, render can take null, undefined, false or true and it will behave the same

Comment: @ritaj No, you cannot directly return `undefined` in a component, take a look at their [API docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render). Though something like `return <div>{undefined}</div>` is possible.

Comment: Well yeah, and the OP did use `{}` bindings `{patient.address[0]
    ? patient.address[0].line[0]
    : null}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this short circuit approach:

```
patient?.address?.0?.line && patient.address[0].line[0]
```